# Qt deployment tidy up folder

Tags: qt, dll, path

Using windeployqt, many files dlls etc will be copied to same folder of the EXE. Is it possible to set so that these dlls are put in another folder so that only EXE file exist in the main program folder?

I tried to manually cut and paste, but of course the EXE becomes non executable after that. I want to do this so that it looks neater and idiot proof because I want to give this app to somebody else to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has it's own DLL search resolve path. You can read the whole document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order). I have never experimented with it, but what comes up on my mind is using some kind of wrapper executable that will either

- Starts an actual .exe from different directory with stored .dll next to it
- Extend PATH variable with path to .dll and then starts actual .exe

Keep in mind this is kinda hacking. In windows systems it is completely normal to have an exe with like quadrilion .dlls next to it. User rarely runs exe itself, user will probably use some kind of app shortcut

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The app will be given to a noob. So i worry he will disturb the other files with the exe. Your idea for wrapper app to call actual app is great I will try that.